# Docker Composer Link MYSQL to IP

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

My 'app' container can access mysql using the host 'mysql:3306'. However, I'm using software which (incorrectly) assumes mysql will be on 127.0.0.1:3306.

Is there a workaround to have 127.0.0.1 point to mysql inside 'app' using docker-compose?

```
services:
    app:
        build:
            context: .
        image: my-image
        ports:
            - 80:80
        links:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
            - 13306:3306
```

Comment: You really can't fix the application to make its database location configurable?  (...how would you run it with a cloud-hosted database like Amazon's RDS offering?  Not just a Docker problem.)

Comment: It is a legacy app. I could edit the source and configure the database references in several locations. I just wondered if, since it is a virtual container environment, mysql could be set to appear on the host expected by the app. This would avoid reconfiguring other apps that are moved to docker. It might be that it can't be done

Comment: if you want them on the same service you can create a new image which contains them both, and exports both the 80 and 3306 ports

Answer (score 1):

You can run your containers on the host network and they will be available on `127.0.0.1`.
Just add `network_mode: "host"` to each of your services and remove the "links" property in your app service like this:

```
services:
app:
    build:
        context: .
    image: my-image
    ports:
        - 80:80
    network_mode: "host" 
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
        - 13306:3306
    network_mode: "host"
```

You can see the spec [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode)

Comment: Note that this basically disables all of Docker's networking functionality.  In this specific example, `ports:` won't work, and you can't make a containerized host-network MySQL not conflict with a non-containerized MySQL; you don't have a choice to hide the containerized database from the outside network.  Fixing the missing configuration in the application seems like a better long-term path.